# WSO2 IS - POST_DELETE_USER error while deleting user from IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We have installed WSO2AM 2.6.0 with IS as KM (5.7). We deployed AM as an active-active all in one instance and IS as KM active-active too following all the directives written on the Official documentation.
Based on the documentation, we created the following databases with their respectives datasources: regdb (registry), carbondb, userdb (user store), mb-store, apimdb.

The issue that we have now is on IS side. We tried several things to check that everything was working correctly, like create users, check registry acces etc. We created a user called "test", chaged some properties, etc and after that, we proceed to delete the user.
When we deleted the user we get the following popup on the IS console:

[image: POST_DELETE_ERROR]

Checking the logs we find the following:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "cm_receipt" does not exist
  Position: 135

TID: [-1234] [] [2020-05-11 09:00:30,062] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  Error when handling event : POST_DELETE_USER 
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
```

We checked on the database and the user was deleted correctly and IS carbon console is not displaying it any more, so the user was correctly deleted. Checking a little bit more, the Delete user process is trying to access table "cm_receipt" on **carbondb**, but the table exists on **apimdb**.

On postgres side, we have this log during the delete:

```
<2020-05-08 11:49:50.452 -03:172.19.35.21(45740):wso2carbon@carbondb:[12476]:>ERROR:  relation "cm_receipt" does not exist at character 135
<2020-05-08 11:49:50.452 -03:172.19.35.21(45740):wso2carbon@carbondb:[12476]:>STATEMENT:  SELECT R.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID, R.LANGUAGE, R.PII_PRINCIPAL_ID, R.PRINCIPAL_TENANT_ID, R.STATE,RS.SP_DISPLAY_NAME,RS.SP_DESCRIPTION FROM CM_RECEIPT R INNER JOIN CM_RECEIPT_SP_ASSOC RS ON R.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID=RS.CONSENT_RECEIPT_ID WHERE PII_PRINCIPAL_ID LIKE $1 AND PRINCIPAL_TENANT_ID =$2 AND SP_NAME LIKE $3 AND STATE LIKE $4 ORDER BY ID  ASC LIMIT $5 OFFSET $6
```

Have you got any idea why it can be happening? There is some bug related or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be two reasons for this.

1. You've forgot to execute the D script which contains the **consent management** tables. `/wso2is-5.7.0/dbscripts/consent/postgresql.sql`.
2. Your `wso2is-5.7.0/repository/conf/consent-mgt-config.xml` configuration file is referring to the wrong datasource.

**Solution**

Check what's the datasource that the `consent-mgt-config.xml` file is referring to. By default it's like this.

```
<ConsentManager xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/consent/management" xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">
    <DataSource>
        <!-- Include a data source name (jndiConfigName) from the set of data sources defined in master-datasources
        .xml -->
        <Name>jdbc/WSO2IdentityDB</Name>
    </DataSource>
```

Here, it's the **jdbc/WSO2IdentityDB**. Then go to your `wso2is-5.7.0/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasource.xml` file and check the database of that datasource. If the mentioned tables are not created in that database you can execute the above mentioned postgre.sql script in that database. (If you've already created these tables in a different datasource, you might want to change the datasource defined in the `consent-mgt-config.xml` file.)

P.S. Never use `-Dsetup` argument for automatic executions of database scripts on the startup. Always manually execute the database scripts against the database.

P.S. The reason for the user deletion success is that this user consent removal process being a **POST_USER_DELETION** event. A failure in a POST handler won't effect the action itself.

Comment: Thanks! We pointed the datasource on consent  Config file to the DB that has the tables already and the error has gone!
Thanks again!